# View pdf from spring get request via react/axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, axios

I have a spring endpoint that serves a pdf as a byte[] and a React ui that is getting a 406 when I try to call the endpoint.

spring endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "report/{report_id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generateReviewTaskReport(
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable("report_id") String reportId,
            @RequestAttribute(USER_ID) String loginId) {

        byte[] report = reportService.generateReport(reportId, loginId);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream =  new ByteArrayInputStream(report);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentLength(report.length);
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + reportId + "_report.pdf");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
    }
```

I've tried:

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportId + "_report.pdf");
```

same result.

react request:

```
export const getReport = (reportId = '') => (dispatch) => {
  const report = `${apiConfig.reportUrl}${reportId}`

  const promise = axios.get(report,
     {
        responseType: 'blob',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/pdf'
      }
    })

  return dispatch({
    type: GET_REPORT,
    payload: promise,
  })
}


case GET_REPORT:
      if (payload.data) {
        const report = new Blob([payload.data])
        reportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(report)
        window.open(reportUrl, "_blank")
      }
```

I've tried responseType: 'bufferArray', returning a plain byte[] from my spring endpoint, always get a 406. I'm guessing it's because I have the wrong mime type in my 'Accept' header. I've tried 'application/pdf' and '*/*', same result. What headers do I need to accept an InputStreamResource or byte[]?

With postman I can download the file just fine.

my config:

```
@Component
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter =
                new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        arrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedMediaTypes());
        return arrayHttpMessageConverter;
    }

    private List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

        return mediaTypes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A general solution, but i think in you'r case it should works fine ;)

```
axios({
  url: 'http://api.dev/file-download', //your url
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
   const link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = url;
   link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
});
```

gist: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Full credits to: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8

Comment: I'm getting a '406 Not Acceptable' response so I'm guessing it has something to do with the headers I set. When I remove those I get the same response. When I change the headers to different mime types I get the same response. Disregarding what I do with the response if it is received it looks like the axios request I posted is functionally identical to the code you suggested. How do you think this would solve the problem of my receiving a 406?

Comment: you can check your headers in postman. Above the "Send" button is the "code" button, tap on it and compare your headers.